# How to observe individual array element changes (update) with Swift and KVO?

Tags: ios, swift, key-value-observing

Do I need to subscribe/unsubscribe to individual elements of an array?

I want to update each table view cell individually to reflect changes in the backing array. By changes I mean not append/remove operations but update of the properties of the objects of the array.
I hope I was able to explain what I want to achieve.
Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To use KVO, declare the model object with `dynamic` properties:

```
class Foo: NSObject {
    @objc dynamic var bar: String   // in Swift 3, `@objc` is not necessary; in Swift 4 we must make this explicit

    init(bar: String) {
        self.bar = bar
        super.init()
    }
}
```

Then, let the cell process the KVO. First, I'd have a protocol by which the cell can inform the table view that it needs to be reloaded:

```
protocol CustomCellDelegate: class {
    func didUpdateObject(for cell: UITableViewCell)
}
```

And the table view controller can conform to this `CustomCellDelegate` protocol and reload the cell when informed it needs to:

```
func didUpdateObject(for cell: UITableViewCell) {
    if let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: cell) {
        tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
    }
}
```

So, and then define cell to setup and handle KVO. In Swift 4 and iOS 11, you can use the closure-based `observe` method with the new strongly typed keys:

```
class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {

    weak var delegate: CustomCellDelegate?

    private var token: NSKeyValueObservation?

    var object: Foo? {
        willSet {
            token?.invalidate()
        }
        didSet {
            textLabel?.text = object?.bar
            token = object?.observe(\.bar) { [weak self] object, change in
                if let cell = self {
                    cell.delegate?.didUpdateObject(for: cell)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In Swift 3:

```
class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {

    private var observerContext = 0

    weak var delegate: CustomCellDelegate?

    var object: Foo? {
        willSet {
            object?.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: #keyPath(Foo.bar), context: &observerContext)
        }
        didSet {
            textLabel?.text = object?.bar
            object?.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: #keyPath(Foo.bar), context: &observerContext)
        }
    }

    override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
        guard context == &observerContext else {
            super.observeValue(forKeyPath: keyPath, of: object, change: change, context: context)
            return
        }

        delegate?.didUpdateObject(for: self)
    }

    deinit {
        object?.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: #keyPath(Foo.bar), context: &observerContext)
    }

}
```

And now the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` can just set the `delegate` and `object` properties:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell

    cell.delegate = self
    cell.object = objects![indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
```

In my opinion, this KVO mechanism is better than the Swift observer mechanism because the model object doesn't need to know (nor should it) anything about the observer. It just needs to indicate that it supports dynamic dispatch, and that's it.

For Swift 2 rendition of the above, see [previous revision of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/37508961/2).

Comment: Thank you Rob. I really liked your approach.

Comment: What's &observerContext in this case, and where does it come from?

Comment: @Eden - The `observeValue(forKeyPath:of:change:context:)` needs some "context" to know if this notification is it is observing, or something its `super` class is observing. So we specify a unique "context" used when creating the observer, and checked when processing the notification. The standard way to do this is to define some variable, in this case `observerContext`, and use its memory address as that unique identifier. It's a common pattern, but I apologize if it wasn't obvious. I've added it above (as well as offering the simpler block-based Swift 4, iOS 11 rendition).

Comment: Using your example, I'm still having a bit of trouble with a "Cannot remove an observer for the key path because it is not registered as an observer." error, and none of the suggested fixes for that error have seemed to work. I'll post my code if it helps, but any ideas off the top of your head? @Rob

Comment: @Eden - I'd suggest adding logging where you add and remove observers and make sure they're balanced, but a common mistake would be `var a = Foo(); a.addObserver(self, ...); a = Foo(); a.removeObserver(...);`, i.e. where you might be dealing w same variable name, but different instance of the class. The observers are associated with the instance of an object, not a variable name. If that's not it, post your own question.

Comment: @Rob thanks for all your help. I also posted a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45805868/using-kvo-within-a-tableview-cell-to-track-changes-to-specific-properties-of-a-c

Comment: @Rob: shouldn't you also use the context when removing the observer in deinit? 
object?.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "bar", context: &observerContext)
The super class might also be observing that same keypath, hence it will attempt to remove itself as observer for that keypath in its deinit method.

Comment: @valeCocoa Given that this is a property that I have created in this subclass, I don't generally have to worry about the superclass having a property of the same name. But it doesn't hurt adding the context to the `removeObserver` call, so I've done so. I've also added use of `#keyPath` to help minimize potential simple typographical errors.

Comment: @Rob: opps my mistake :) I haven't seen the observed property was also the one created in the subclass. I also forgot to thank you for clarifying so well KVO in Swift. Coming from OBJ-C, I was having some trouble adopting this pattern in SWIFT, and your answer is great.

Comment: too much code only to observe an array update, it must be a better way to do that. that's overwhelming.

Answer (score 2):

You could use setter observer on stored variables in the backing array.

```
var s = "myString" {
    willSet {
        // do the update on the cell here with newValue
    }
    didSet {
        // do something with oldValue
    }
}
var array: [String] = []
array.append(s)
```

when you change the value in `array` the willSet and didSet is executed, and you can call a function on the cell doing the update you want.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a delegate to handle communication between the individual cell:s data (say, elements of your array) and the owner of these cells (i.e., owner of the array). Changes in the "backing array" can be propagated to the array owned using delegate callbacks with appropriate information.

E.g.:

```
/* delegate protocol blueprinting delegate callback methods */
protocol MyDelegate: class {
    func arrayEntryUpdated(element: Foo)
}

/* lets assume your table view cells data source are Foo objects */
class Foo {
    var id: Int = -1
    private var bar : String = "" {
        didSet {
            /* notify the delegate each time the bar
               property of a Foo object is set */
            delegate?.arrayEntryUpdated(self)
        }
    }

    weak var delegate: MyDelegate?
}

/* you can then hande individual updates of the Foo objects via
   delegate callbacks to the owner of the Foo array */
class MyArrayOwningClass: MyDelegate {
    var fooArr : [Foo]

    init(fooArr: [Foo]) {
        self.fooArr = fooArr
        self.fooArr.enumerate().forEach { $1.id = $0; $1.delegate = self }
    }

    // MyDelegate
    func arrayEntryUpdated(element: Foo) {
        print("Foo element of id #\(element.id) updated.")
            // ... in your case, handle individual cell updating
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
let fooArr = [Foo(), Foo(), Foo()] // "data source"
let owner = MyArrayOwningClass(fooArr: fooArr)

// update an element of the data source
fooArr[1].bar = "bar" // via delegate: "Foo element of id #1 updated."
```