# Is there a way to implement substring getters and setters for a computed property?

Tags: swift

I'm trying to use a computed property as an Array object, like so:

```
var arrayComputed: [String] {
    get {
        ...
    }

    set(newValue) {
        ...
    }
}
```

However, now I'm trying to set values inside the computed array, and I have no idea how this should be implemented. My setter is set up assuming that it is being given a whole array to store, but what if it was being set like this?

```
arrayComputed[4] = "Some string"
```

How would this even behave?

Comment: Related: [How to observe individual array element changes (update) with Swift and KVO?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37507760/how-to-observe-individual-array-element-changes-update-with-swift-and-kvo)

Comment: @dfri what he is probably looking for is willSet and didSet. `var computedArray: [String] = [ ] {
    willSet { print(newValue) }
    didSet { print(oldValue)   }` If he needs to manage how the array gets populated he can do it inside didSet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some digging and found the solution. Setting using a subscript on a computed array property provides a `newValue` containing the original array, but with the relevant index changed according to the subscript that was used. To illustrate:

```
var actualArray: [String] = []

var computedArray: [String] {
    get {
        return actualArray
    }

    set(setTo) {
        actualArray = setTo
    }
}

computedArray.append("Hello")
computedArray.append("Matt")
computedArray.append("World")

// computedArray and actualArray are now both ["Hello", "Matt", "World"]

computedArray[1] = "Jacob"

// computedArray and actualArray are now both ["Hello", "Jacob", "World"]
```