# How to use KVO to update tableViewCells based on underlying array element changes?

Tags: ios, swift, key-value-observing

I have a table view representing an underlying array. The cells have a label and a slider which should show the value of the `percentage` property of the array.

I want to use key-value observing to update the label whenever the percentage property changes. (I know KVO is overkill in this example but eventually sliding one slider will affect the other cells including the position of the slider and the underlying array will be set from multiple places in the app and at any time so KVO is the way to go.)

I've had a bunch of help [from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37507760/how-to-observe-individual-array-element-changes-update-with-swift-and-kvo), but I can't get it to fire and update the label. I'm including all my code here. Not sure where I'm going wrong.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, CustomCellDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self

        for i in 0...4 {
            items.append(Items(ID: i, percentage: 50))
        }
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return items.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: myTableViewCell.ID) as? myTableViewCell {
            cell.object = items[indexPath.row]
            cell.mySlider.tag = indexPath.row

            return cell

        } else {
            return UITableViewCell()
        }

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 100
    }


    @IBAction func sliderValueChanged(_ sender: UISlider) {
        items[sender.tag].percentage = Double(sender.value)
        print("percentage at \(items[sender.tag].ID) is \(items[sender.tag].percentage)")
    }

    func didUpdateObject(for cell: UITableViewCell) {
        if let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: cell) {
            tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
            print("hello")
        }
    }
}

class myTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    static let ID = "myCell"
    weak var delegate: CustomCellDelegate?
    private var token: NSKeyValueObservation?

    var object: Items? {
        willSet {
            token?.invalidate()
        }
        didSet {
            myLabel.text = "\(object?.percentage ?? 0)"
            token = object?.observe(\.percentage) { [weak self] object, change in
                if let cell = self {
                    cell.delegate?.didUpdateObject(for: cell)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var myLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var mySlider: UISlider!

}

class Items: NSObject {
    let ID: Int
    @objc dynamic var percentage: Double

    init(ID: Int, percentage: Double){
        self.ID = ID
        self.percentage = percentage
        super.init()
    }
}

var items: [Items] = []


protocol CustomCellDelegate: class {
    func didUpdateObject(for cell: UITableViewCell)
}
```

[image: Label not updating]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To do the KVO in Swift 4, you have to declare the property as `dynamic` and call `observe(_:options:changeHandler:)` on that object, saving the resulting `NSKeyValueObservation` token. When that token falls out of scope (or replaced with another token), the original observer will automatically be removed.

In your case, you have your observer calling the delegate, which then reloads the cell. But you never appear to set that `delegate` property, so I suspect that method isn't getting called.

But this all seems a bit fragile. I'd be inclined to just update the label directly in the observer's `changeHandler`. I also think you can do a more direct updating of the cell (I'd put the "value changed" IBAction in the cell, not the table view), and eliminate that rather awkward use of the `tag` to identify which row in the model array had its slider updated (which can be problematic if you insert or delete rows).

So consider this object:

```
class CustomObject: NSObject {
    let name: String
    @objc dynamic var value: Float       // this is the property that the custom cell will observe

    init(name: String, value: Float) {
        self.name = name
        self.value = value

        super.init()
    }
}
```

You could then have a table view controller that populates an array of `objects` with instances of this model type. The details here are largely unrelated to the observation (which we'll cover below), but I include this just to provide a complete example:

```
class ViewController: UITableViewController {

    var objects: [CustomObject]!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // self sizing cells

        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 60
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension

        // populate model with random data

        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = .spellOut

        objects = (0 ..< 1000).map {
            CustomObject(name: formatter.string(for: $0)!, value: 0.5)
        }
    }
}

// MARK: - UITableViewDataSource

extension ViewController {
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return objects?.count ?? 0
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
        cell.object = objects[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
}
```

Having done that, you can now have the base class for your cell (a) update the model object if the slider changes; and (b) observe changes to that `dynamic` property, in this example updating the label when the `value`  changes are observed in the model object:

```
class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var valueLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var valueSlider: UISlider!

    static private let formatter: NumberFormatter = {
        let _formatter = NumberFormatter()
        _formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
        _formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 2
        _formatter.minimumIntegerDigits = 1
        return _formatter
    }()

    private var token: NSKeyValueObservation?

    weak var object: CustomObject? {
        didSet {
            let value = object?.value ?? 0

            nameLabel.text = object?.name
            valueLabel.text = CustomCell.formatter.string(for: value)
            valueSlider.value = value

            token = object?.observe(\.value) { [weak self] object, change in
                self?.valueLabel.text = CustomCell.formatter.string(for: object.value)
            }
        }
    }

    @IBAction func didChangeSlider(_ slider: UISlider) {
        object?.value = slider.value
    }
}
```

That yields:

[image]

For more information, see the "Key-Value Observing" section of the [Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C: Adopting Cocoa Patterns](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/AdoptingCocoaDesignPatterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH7-ID6).

Comment: Thank-you so much @Rob. I have worked the examples into my implementation and it works. And I mostly get it. Will be going over it more to fully grok it. Really appreciate your help! The Swift is strong with you. 

Answer (score 0):

hi @sean problem is in UITableview cell class you have already make diSet Method , so you dont need to pass value for cell.lable and slider Just try below code

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: myTableViewCell.ID) as? myTableViewCell {
        //pass the object to which you wanna add observer to cell
        cell.object = items[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    } else {
        return UITableViewCell()
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried this and still I can't get the label to update. I've edited the question to reflect the code changes. Is there anything you can see which is still wrong? Thanks for your help.